# Matrix masking operation in OpenCV(C++) and in Matlab

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, matrix, image-masking

I would like to do the following operation (which is at the current state  in Matlab) using cv::Mat variables.

I have matrix mask:

```
mask =

 1     0     0
 1     0     1
```

then matrix M:

```
M =

 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 6
 3
```

and samples = M(mask,:)

```
samples =

 1
 2
 6
```

My question is, how can I perform the same operation like, M(mask,:), with OpenCV?

Comment: I guess that `mask` and `M` are matrix but what would be the type of `samples` ?

Comment: @Gabriel Devillers that would be matrix (cv::Mat) as well. The above presented example is just given with random numbers and sizes, but keeping the same meaning for the real task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With my knowledge the closet function to this thing is `copyTo` function in `opencv` that get `matrix` and `mask` for inputs. but this function hold original structure of your matrix you can test it.

I think there is no problem to use `for` loop in opencv(in c++) because it's fast. I propose to use `for` loop with below codes.

```
Mat M=(Mat_<uchar>(2,3)<<1,2,3,4,5,6); //Create M
cout<<M<<endl;

Mat mask=(Mat_<bool>(2,3)<<1,0,0,1,0,1); // Create mask
cout<<mask<<endl;

Mat samples;
///////////////////////////////
for(int i=0;i<M.total();i++)
{
    if(mask.at<uchar>(i))
        samples.push_back(M.at<uchar>(i));
}
cout<<samples<<endl;
```

above code result below outputs.

```
[  1,   2,   3;
   4,   5,   6]

[  1,   0,   0;
   1,   0,   1]

[  1;
   4;
   6]
```

with using copyTo your output will be like below

```
[1 0 0
 4 0 6];
```

[image]